# responsive table in HTML/CSS with first cell acting as a full row

Tags: html, css, responsive

I need to create a responsive table in HTML/CSS. I need that first cell of the row acts as a full row when the space becomes tight, just like below. In any situation, colums (c2, c3, c4) should remains vertically aligned (cells one below the other), just like a normal table. Any idea?

Normal view:

```
+-----------------------+--------+------+------+
|           c1          |   c2   |   c3 |  c4  |
+-----------------------+--------+------+------+
```

Mobile view:

```
+---------------------+
|           c1        |
+---------+------+----+
|   c2    |   c3 | c4 |
+---------+------+----+
|           c1        |
+---------+------+----+
|   c2    |   c3 | c4 |
+---------+------+----+
```

Comment: Well, I think it won't be table anymore, It's more like grid

Comment: In addition to what @ishidex2 said, you indicate repeating `c1` multiple times. That's inconsistent with CSS grid (or tables for that matter). You'd need to create additional elements and only display them on mobile.

Comment: This can not be done with HTML tables and CSS. Look at [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Comment: It can be done with media queries.

Comment: @JonP It can be done with HTML tables and CSS. Using CSS, you can override the `display` property of table elements to make them behave like block elements, flex elements, etc.

Comment: @sean if you change the `display` property,  you lose the "tableness" of columns sizing based on cell content. I am more than happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: Well OK it is possible..... but if you're going to strictly stick to tables, it is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Here I am using JavaScript to toggle classes on and off to show how the styling can change. However, you can achieve the same effect
through media queries by not defining the `span.mobile` and `.grid.mobile` styles when the size is bigger than a specified breakpoint.

See [this article](https://medium.com/evodeck/responsive-data-tables-with-css-grid-3c58ecf04723) for more information on how to make a responsive table using a grid.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.mobile');
setInterval(() => {
  elements.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('mobile'));
}, 1000);
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

/* toggle below style with a media query */
.grid.mobile {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.grid > span {
  padding: 4px 4px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

/* toggle below style with a media query */
span.mobile {
  grid-column: 1 /4;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid mobile">
  <span class="mobile">c1</span>
  <span>c2</span>
  <span>c3</span>
  <span>c4</span>
  <span class="mobile">c1</span>
  <span>c2</span>
  <span>c3</span>
  <span>c4</span>
  <span class="mobile">c1</span>
  <span>c2</span>
  <span>c3</span>
  <span>c4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible with media queries, but this particular approach is ugly and involves duplication.

Have a dedicated row for mobile. Hide and show this row with media queries. Use the same media query to hide the cell on mobile.

```css
#table {
  width: 100%;
}

.mRow {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .mRow {
    display: table-row;
  }
  .dCell {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <!-- this row is hidden by default, shown with a media query -->
  <tr class="mRow">
    <td colspan="3">C1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- this cell hidden on mobile with a media query -->
    <td class="dCell">C1</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>C4</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- this row is hidden by default, shown with a media query -->
  <tr class="mRow">
    <td colspan="3">C1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- this cell hidden on mobile with a media query -->
    <td class="dCell">C1</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>C4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```